# How do you "format" data after retrieving it in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, eloquent

I often parse or format data after pulling it from the database, **for example** to "humanize" dates before giving feeding them to the view.

This is the code I have, it works but the `format()` step has to be done manually after each request, on all the results.

```
class Article extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = 'articles';

    public function format()
    {
        $this->formatted_date = date("M. j, Y", strtotime($this->date));
        $this->body = auto_paragraph(texturize($this->body));
    }
}
```

and

```
class Front_Articles_Controller extends Base_Controller
{
    public function action_index() {
        $vars['articles'] = Article::take(10)->get();

        // this is the loop I want to avoid
        foreach ($vars['articles'] as &$article) {
            $article->format();
        }

        return View::make('front.articles.index', $vars);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have this formatting function be called automatically on all the Articles or is this the only solution?

Comment: take a look at [laravel Accessors and Mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: Format your data before inserting it in the database. So when you retrieve you don't have to format again

Answer (score 1):

for dates, following is straightforward

```
class Article extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = 'articles';

    protected $dates = ['date'];
}
```

And the `$article->date` will be converted to a `Carbon` object which is an extended DateTime object.

For other properties, try to use the accessor:

```
class Article extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = 'articles';

    public function getBodyAttribute($value)
    {
        return auto_paragraph(texturize($value));
    }
}
```

And then in your controller, `$article->body` will have the formatted value.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the **Presenter Pattern**. This will decouple the raw data (your models) from how you want it presented.

Following [this tutorial](http://joycse06.github.io/blog/2015/01/laravel-view-presenters-from-scratch/)
 you should end up with something like this:

**Model:**

```
class Article extends Eloquent {
  public static $table = 'articles';
  // $dates will automatically mutate your date to a Carbon object
  protected $dates = ['date'];
}
```

**Presenter:**

```
Class ArticlePresenter extends Presenter {
  public function formattedDate()
  {
    // format is a method of Carbon object
    return $this->date->format("M. j, Y");
  }
}
```

**Usage(in view):**

```
@foreach($articles as $article) 
  {{ $article->present()->formattedDate }}
@endforeach
```

**N.B:** for dates manipulation you should use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: I like this pattern. Perhaps it can be made more transparent, though: https://github.com/laravel-auto-presenter/laravel-auto-presenter

Comment: @bfred.it https://github.com/robclancy/presenter is a great presenter package, as well.

Answer (score 0):

this might help or give you a starting point.

```
class Article extends Eloquent {

public static $table = 'articles';
// set accessor
public function getDateformat($date)
  {
    return date("M. j, Y", strtotime($this->date));

  }
/ /set mutator
public function setDateformat($date)
  {
   // your code here

  }
}
```

Comment: Who's feature is that? Laravel/Eloquent?

Comment: it is Eloquentn feature